# "Instagram Testers" are not visible on Roles if Facebook app type is "Business"?

Tags: facebook, roles, instagram-graph-api

I am not able to see Instagram Testers roles on [https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{AppID}/roles/roles/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%7BAppID%7D/roles/roles/)

How can I test direct messages coming from Instagram?
Why Instagram Testers are not visible if app type is Business

Comment: I don't see it either and my app type is "Consumer". Seems like the documentation is incomplete. 